# How to sign an InputStream from a PDF file with PDFBox 2.0.0

Tags: java, pdf, inputstream, pdfbox, signing

I want to sign a InputStream from a PDF file without using a temporary file.
Here I convert InputStream to File and this work fine :

```
InputStream inputStream = this.signatureObjPAdES.getSignatureDocument().getInputStream();
OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:/temp.pdf"));
int read = 0;
byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

while ((read = inputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
    outputStream.write(bytes, 0, read);
}

PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File("C:/temp.pdf"));

...

document.addSignature(new PDSignature(this.dts.getDocumentTimeStamp()), this);
document.saveIncremental(new FileOutputStream("C:/result.pdf");
document.close();
```

But I want to do this directly :

```
PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(inputStream);
```

Problem: at run

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.pdfbox.io.RandomAccessBufferedFileInputStream.<init>(RandomAccessBufferedFileInputStream.java:77)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.saveIncremental(PDDocument.java:961)
```

All ideas are welcome. 
Thank you.

EDIT:
It's now working with the release of PDFBox 2.0.0.

Comment: looks like a bug to me, although I suspect that the fix will be to throw an exception. IIRC, saveIncremental just appends to an existing file, so it isn't possible with load(inputStream). Please open an issue in PDFBox JIRA.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr It at least will require some tweaking to make that run disk-less as some assumptions true for a `FileInputStream` but not in general are made in `COSWriter` concerning `incrementalInput`, e.g. that `available()` returns the exact whole stream lengths.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The cause

The immediate hindrance is in the method `PDDocument.saveIncremental()` itself:

> ```
> public void saveIncremental(OutputStream output) throws IOException
> {
>     InputStream input = new RandomAccessBufferedFileInputStream(incrementalFile);
>     COSWriter writer = null;
>     try
>     {
>         writer = new COSWriter(output, input);
>         writer.write(this, signInterface);
>         writer.close();
>     }
>     finally
>     {
>         if (writer != null)
>         {
>             writer.close();
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> *([PDDocument.java](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/pdfbox/trunk/pdfbox/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/PDDocument.java))*

The member `incrementalFile` used in the first line is only set during a `PDDocument.load` with a `File` parameter.

Thus, this method cannot be used.

### A work-around

Fortunately the method `PDDocument.saveIncremental()` only uses methods and values publicly available with the sole exception of `signInterface`, but you know the value of it because you set it in your code in the line right before the `saveIncremental` call:

```
document.addSignature(new PDSignature(this.dts.getDocumentTimeStamp()), this);
document.saveIncremental(new FileOutputStream("C:/result.pdf"));
```

Thus, instead of calling `PDDocument.saveIncremental()` you can do the equivalent in your code.

To do so you furthermore need a replacement value for the `InputStream input`. It needs to return a stream with the identical content as `inputStream` in your

```
PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(inputStream);
```

So you need to use that stream twice. As you have not said whether that `inputStream` can be reset, we'll first copy it into a `byte[]` which we forward both to `PDDocument.load` and `new COSWriter`.

Thus, replace your

```
PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(inputStream);

...

document.addSignature(new PDSignature(this.dts.getDocumentTimeStamp()), this);
document.saveIncremental(new FileOutputStream("C:/result.pdf"));
document.close();
```

by

```
byte[] inputBytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);
PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new ByteArrayInputStream(inputBytes));

...

document.addSignature(new PDSignature(this.dts.getDocumentTimeStamp()), this);
saveIncremental(new FileOutputStream("C:/result.pdf"),
    new ByteArrayInputStream(inputBytes), document, this);
document.close();
```

and add a new method `saveIncremental` to your class inspired by the original `PDDocument.saveIncremental()`:

```
void saveIncremental(OutputStream output, InputStream input, PDDocument document, SignatureInterface signatureInterface) throws IOException
{
    COSWriter writer = null;
    try
    {
        writer = new COSWriter(output, input);
        writer.write(document, signatureInterface);
        writer.close();
    }
    finally
    {
        if (writer != null)
        {
            writer.close();
        }
    }
}
```

### On the side

I said above

> As you have not said whether that `inputStream` can be reset, we'll first copy it into a `byte[]` which we forward both to `PDDocument.load` and `new COSWriter`.

Actually there is another reason to do so: `COSWriter.doWriteSignature()` retrieves the length of the original PDF like this:

> ```
> long inLength = incrementalInput.available();
> ```
>
> *([COSWriter.java](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/pdfbox/trunk/pdfbox/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/pdfwriter/COSWriter.java))*

The documentation of `InputStream.available()` states, though:

> Note that while some implementations of `InputStream` will return the total number of bytes in the stream, many will not.

To re-use `inputStream` instead of using a `byte[]` and `ByteArrayInputStream`s as above, therefore, `inputStream` not only needs to support `reset()` but  also needs to be one of the few `InputStream` implementations which return the total number of bytes in the stream as `available`.

`FileInputStream` and `ByteArrayInputStream` both do return the total number of bytes in the stream as `available`.

There may still be more issues when using generic `InputStream`s instead of these two.

Comment: Thank you mkl. I will use this new method pending changes to the `saveIncremental()` PDFBox 2.0.0 method.

Answer (score 1):

Hey [Cyril Bremaud](/users/3913345/cyril-bremaud), you can use this approach, since the `PDDocument` class has 3 overloaded constructor, you can go ahead and provide only the file path if you like and it will work as well. But for your requirement to be able to pass an `InputStream` directly to the `PDDocument` constructor, use this code:

```
lStrInputPDFfile = "samples_pdf_signing\Country Calendar.pdf";
lOsPDFInput = new java.io.FileInputStream(lStrInputPDFfile);
jPDFDocument = new org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument().load(lOsPDFInput);
```

But this also work in my case:

```
lStrInputPDFfile = "samples_pdf_signing\Country Calendar.pdf";
jPDFDocument = new org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument().load(lStrInputPDFfile);
```

Note: `InputStream is a parent class of FileInputStream and that is why the above code works.

updated my code, please check again. Thanks to [@mkl](/users/1729265/mkl) for pointing that out.

Comment: All `PDDocument.load` overloads are static and return a new PDDocument instance with the loaded PDF. Thus, after your `jPDFDocument.load(lOsPDFInput)` the `jPDFDocument` still is empty and the `PDDocument` into which the stream was loaded is completely ignored.

Comment: Furthermore the OP clearly indicates that his problem occurs during `PDDocument.saveIncremental`, and not during `PDDocument.load`.

Comment: hey thanks man, updated my code, please check again. Thanks [@mkl](/users/1729265/mkl) pointing that out.

Comment: Should change it to use PDDocument().load(lOsPDFINput) to access that method in a static way